# compute variance per row in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

as it is said in the title, I want to compute the variance per row in my dataset, all columns are continuous :
I have tried to use the rowVars function from the package matrixStats, but it doesn't work

```
x[, variance := rowVars(.SD), .SDcols=varQuant]
```

I have the following error :

```
Error in rowVars(.SD): Argument 'x' must be a matrix or a vector.
```

Comment: try: `x[, variance := apply(.SD,1,var), .SDcols=varQuant]`

Answer (score 3):

Another way, using data.table:

```
library(matrixStats)
library(data.table)
x[, variance := rowVars(as.matrix(.SD))]
```

You just forgot the as.matrix part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#Toy data.frame with two rows
df<-data.table(rbind(runif(100,10,100),runif(100,10,100)))

#Apply var function to each row
apply(df,1,var)
[1] 726.3197 652.2919
```

Comment: Title specified "data.table".

Comment: It's the same as you can see: df<-data.table(rbind(runif(100,10,100),runif(100,10,100)))
> apply(df,1,var)
[1] 637.2838 617.6317